# How can i set a sql server user to execute stored procredures in readonly mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to set a readony permission to a database user.
This  user should have permission to execute stored procedures
But this user should not have permission to update or inser or alter anything in database through these stored procedures or through any methord
can anyone help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply don't grant permission on the stored procs that change data.

Otherwise, you could use triggers on the tables to check, but that's a bit silly compared to using permissions correctly

Note: [ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) means that permissions on tables won't be checked, even DENY, so this won't work.

Comment: thanks.. ownership chaining... that was a good information to me

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Set the [`EXECUTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187797.aspx) permission for that user, then they'll only be able to execute the Stored Procedures in your database.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.storedprocedurename TO SQLUSERNAME;
```

Comment: thats fine, but what if the procedures has update or insert querys? , that also will be get executed. i need to restrict that.

Comment: Then why would you grant execute permission to the stored procedure if they can't run it as it's meant to be run?  Does it do a `SELECT` before the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements?

Comment: yes.. i do a select in tyhe sp's.i need this user to execute only those sp's with select statements only

Comment: Then create a list of those stored procedures and run the `GRANT` command on those SPs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the permissions on a procedure by procedure basis. Give them permission to stored procedures that select, and don't give them permission to the stored procedures that do updates or inserts.The best way is to setup roles, and add the users to the roles.

This is pretty flexible and you can use it to restrict exactly what uses can do. For example, it may actually be okay for them to update a table as long as they do it through a certain stored procedure. To do this you can deny them all permission to that table, but grant them permission to execute the stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

give execute permission on the proc and make sure the user doesn't have write access to the tables used by the proc. Check if he is not member of the db_datawriter roled.

If you want to be 100% sure, add the user to the db_denydatawriter role

Comment: i want something like this.. but unfortunately this didint work. i think the execute permission overrides the  db_denydatawriter role.The user can still update data tho that sp